# Does firewalld require system reboot for changes to become effective

Tags: networking, firewall, firewalld

On a `vagrant` Ubuntu 18.04.02 box

```
root@ubuntu-bionic:~# ss -tulanp | grep -i 3306
root@ubuntu-bionic:~# docker run -d --rm -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root" -p 3306:3306 -v mysql_volume:/var/lib/mysql --name test_mysql mysql:5.7
29401546117d55b5b8d122a225352a6534cf8a9bbb611a195adbbe3ff7341909
root@ubuntu-bionic:~# ss -tulanp | grep -i 3306
tcp   LISTEN  0       128                        *:3306                *:*       users:(("docker-proxy",pid=1986,fd=4)) 
root@ubuntu-bionic:~# firewall-cmd --list-all
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client
  ports: 3306/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
root@ubuntu-bionic:~# hostname -I
10.0.2.15 192.168.33.10 172.17.0.1
```

Then on my host machine:

```
/home/pkaramol/VirtualBox VMs
$ nc -zv -w 2 192.168.33.10 3306
Connection to 192.168.33.10 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!
```

I will try now to remove the port `3306` that I had explicitly added:

back to my `vagrant` machine:

```
root@ubuntu-bionic:~# firewall-cmd --remove-port=3306/tcp --zone=public --permanent
success
root@ubuntu-bionic:~# firewall-cmd --reload
success
root@ubuntu-bionic:~# firewall-cmd --list-all
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Back to my host machine:

```
$ nc -zv -w 2 192.168.33.10 3306
Connection to 192.168.33.10 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!
```

Why isn't reload making the new state applicable right away?

The problem goes away after a reboot of the `vagrant` machine, in which case I get

```
$ nc -zv -w 2 192.168.33.10 3306
nc: connect to 192.168.33.10 port 3306 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not encountered such an issue . Just a guess,  but what happens if you try (This is not the recommended practice )`firewall-cmd --complete-reload` that reloads  even kernel filters and it will terminate any connection